# How do I make my stepper or servo move a certain way when a button on my ir remote is pressed?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, motor, ir, robotics

Hi i am making a robot arm and I am trying to get my stepper and servo to move the direction that is pressed on the ir remote. I am using a sg90 and a stepper motor with 2048 steps. The ir receiver is picking up a ton of 0s in the serial monitor only when the code is run and everything is plugged in. Maybe that's the issue.
this is my code

```
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Stepper.h>

const int in_4 = A0;
const int in_3 = A1;
const int in_2 = A2;
const int in_1 = A3;
int motorspeed = 5;
#define IR_RECEIVE_PIN 9

#define UPpin 70
#define DOWNpin 21
#define LEFTpin 68
#define RIGHTpin 67

int command; // Declare command variable

Stepper LR(2048, in_1, in_3, in_2, in_4);
Servo servo; // Add semicolon here

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  servo.attach(2);
  LR.setSpeed(motorspeed);
  IrReceiver.begin(IR_RECEIVE_PIN, ENABLE_LED_FEEDBACK); // You should initialize IrReceiver object
}

void loop() {
 if (IrReceiver.decode()) {
    IrReceiver.resume();
    command = IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command; // Assign value to command
    Serial.println(command);
  }
  if (command == RIGHTpin) {
  LR.step(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is frowned upon to created a second account and gain reputation by editing your own posts. You seem to have two accounts:  [zachlikestech](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/95803/zachlikestech) and [zachlickstech123](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/97032/zachlickstech123). You can merge accounts, see [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)